# how to execute bat file (.bat) by use command robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have one

> script.bat

and i want to excute this script it in robotframework .

I'm also try with this but nothing work for me .

```
Run     ${CURDIR}/script/script.bat
```

Anyone could help me please ?

Comment: Can you explain what error or message you're seeing?

Comment: @A.Koostra , It doesn't show any erorr . It's PASS , but nothing execute . Now i'm solve this problem by create custom code in python . thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [Process Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) to run bat file

Then your snippet wil be like

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process

*** Test Case ***
Launch Bat File
    Run Process       ${CURDIR}/script/script.bat
```

I tested above snippet using sample bat file(script.bat) which launch chrome.

```
start chrome https://www.google.co.in/
```

Even i tried with **OperatingSystem library** and it's working fine. Following is the snippet.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Case ***
Lauch Bat File
    Run       ${CURDIR}/script/script.bat
```

Comment: I am  already do this also , but it's wont work . I'm solve this problem by create custom my own library now . anyway thanks you .

Comment: Yes, New chrome is launched. Try above example and don't forget to include library in settings.