# How to execute .bat file, Robot Framework

Tags: file, pycharm, robotframework

I am trying to execute my .bat script in robot framework. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924613/how-to-execute-bat-file-bat-by-use-command-robot-framework) answer on stackoverflow. But the question didn't really get a correct answer. I have tried to run:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process

*** Test Case ***
Launch Bat File
    Run Process       ${CURDIR}/script.bat
```

I got error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I then tried:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Case ***
Lauch Bat File
    Run       ${CURDIR}/script.bat
```

The test passed, but nothing was executed

Next I tried inputting my script.bat as a resource:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem
Resource  ${CURDIR}/script.bat

*** Test Case ***
Lauch Bat File
    Run       ${CURDIR}/script.bat
```

Error: Unsupported file format 'bat'.

I'm unsure about the first two errors. But for the "unsupported .bat" error, I downloaded the automatic plugins that PyCharm told me to in order to support my bat file. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried the [Run Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process) keyword in the Process Library?

Comment: You sure the path is correct, and the .bat script is correct, and it actually does something so you can observe it?

Comment: @A.Kootstra: it's in the first example

Comment: Run and Run Process are different keywords, and part of different libraries.

Comment: @pavelsaman Yes, the path is correct. For the .bat script, I got it from https://github.com/adiralashiva8/robotframework-metrics so I can get some metrics for every test I run. It's the "Generate robotframework-metrics after execution"

Comment: @A.Kootstra Could you give me an example of what you mean? Because I think I am doing what you are suggesting.

Comment: I checked the robotmetrics github page, and I think there's no need to execute a .bat script that's supposed to create reports from RF in RF. Why are you trying to do this in RF? The README doesn't say that. It says you run your tests (e.g. `robot Tests/*`) and then you run robotmetrics (e.g. `robotmetrics`). Naturally, you want robotmetrics to run after your tests, so you would type: `robot Tests/* && robotmetrics`. That's it. Why put it into a .bat file and write a new test case for this?

Comment: @pavelsaman Thanks for the clarifying questions. So the .bat script is supposed to generate Robotframework metrics after execution of my tests. This way I don't have to type: `robot Tests/* && robotmetrics` everytime. The reason why I wrote a new test case is to narrow down my problem for you guys: My problem being that I cannot execute a .bat script

Comment: I'd leave that RF test case that executes the .bat file out of this for the time being. If you execute you .bat `> run-and-report.bat` from the command line, what happens? Do you perhaps get the first error ([WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified)? Are both robot and robotmetrics in `%PATH%`?

Answer (score 1):

If I take the comments into account, I'll answer the question like this.

My example RF test suite looks like:

**test.robot**

```
*** Test Cases *** 
Log
    Log To Console    abc
```

I've created a .bat file with the following content:

**test-and-report.bat**

```
@echo off
robot test.robot && robotmetrics
```

Now I can run `> test-and-report.bat`, which runs the test and then creates a robotmetrics report in the same directory.

---

However, your original question was about how to run a .bat file form RF. I don't think you want to do this in this situation, but I'll demonstrate it anyway.

**test.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process    

*** Test Cases *** 
Open Chrome
    Run Process    ${CURDIR}/open-chrome.bat
```

And the .bat file.

**open-chrome.bat**

```
@echo off
start chrome
```

Then I can run: `> robot test.robot` from the same directory where `test.robot` is present and Chrome will open.

Comment: Thank you for this. I really appreciate it. And it looks like you are right about not using RF for executing the .bat file. I messaged the developer himself about his code and he said not to use RF to execute the .bat file but to use the terminal instead. So the answers given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924613/how-to-execute-bat-file-bat-by-use-command-robot-framework will not work.

Comment: @JasonMason: And the first approach without RF works? Or are you experiencing some problems/errors?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes, it works perfectly with no problems. You're awesome!